# как поменять varchar to text mysql

Tags: mysql

Не могу нигде найти. Как поменять в базе тип строки с varchar на text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]войди на http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ выбери свой база и свой table потом структура и в какой строку хочеш изменить нажми изменить потом выбери  text но только тогда когда вы работаете на phpmyadmin
а если нет то

ALTER TABLE `TABLENAME` CHANGE `FIELDNAME` `FIELDNAME` TEXT NULL;

запрос на MYSQL

Comment: В тегах нет phpmyadmin, почему вы предлагаете его в качестве решения? Вопрос риторический.

Comment: @Anamnian теперь понятно когда автор запроса отметил  мой ответ правельный

Comment: теперь если не сложно  убери свой минус на ответ

Comment: Я выразил свое сугубо субъективное мнение, проголосовав против данного вопроса и конкретно этого ответа. Может найдутся пользователи кому по душе ваш ответ, и они проголосуют "За" по нему. Пользователь у которого такая же проблема, но который не имеет phpmyadmin, не получит пользы от вашего ответа. Вы можете дополнить/изменить свой ответ, тогда я пересмотрю свою оценку.

Comment: вот так доволен

Comment: Этот способ мог не сработать? Т.к. у меня обрезалось все что больше 128 символов, я поменял varchar(128) на text и проблема не решилась

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE `TABLENAME` CHANGE `FIELDNAME` `FIELDNAME` TEXT NULL;
```

http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ALTER_TABLE.html